# Meu repeater não renderiza no browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

Criei um repeater e não consigo renderizá-lo. Quando eu inspeciono o objeto, ele não aparece. Peguei o código acima dele, chamado de Analisar dados cadastrais e repeti após o repeater e consigo visualizar, mas o repeater não. O que pode estar errado? Abaixo o código a partir de Analisar dados cadastrais:

```
<div class="boxAprovacao">
        <h2>Analisar dados cadastrais</h2>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdPendencia" runat="server" />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIcAprovado" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Aprovar" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Reprovar" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>     
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtParecerDadosCadastrais" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" CssClass="parecerAnalista" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdUsuario" runat="server" />

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptHistoricoAnalises" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHistoricoAnalises_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <h3>Histórico de análises</h3>
            <dl>    
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <dt>
                Por:
                <asp:Label Text="ANA LUCIA ALVES MARTINS" ID="lblHistAnaNmAnalista" runat="server" /><br />
                Em: <asp:Label Text="03/12/2014" ID="lblHistAnaData" runat="server" /> - <asp:Label Text="10:19" ID="lblHistAnaHorario" runat="server" />
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque bibendum diam augue, ut varius lectus luctus a. Sed finibus fringilla nibh. Quisque orci erat, iaculis quis neque vitae, maximus vehicula tortor. Praesent luctus venenatis venenatis. Nullam non lacus orci. Vivamus convallis hendrerit urna, vel facilisis sapien semper non." ID="lblHistAnaParacerAnalista" runat="server" />
            </dd>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
            </dl>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Então, a dúvida toda é porque tenho vários repeater em meu projeto e nenhum deles eu tenho um DataSource assim, explícito conforme vocês estão me dizendo para fazer. Veja esse exemplo que eu tenho aqui no meu projeto de um repeater que funciona e não tem nada assim tão explícito.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTitulares" runat="server" 
            onitemcommand="rptTitulares_ItemCommand" 
            OnItemDataBound="rptTitulares_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="970px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th class="nameSize">Nome</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>E-mail</th>
                                <th>Data Cadastro</th>
                            </tr>    
                        </thead>    
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Excluir" ID="lkbExcluirTitular" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir o Titular selecionado ?');"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Exibir ficha"  ID="lkbExibirFicha" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="CdPessoa" Value='<%# Eval("CdPessoa")%>' runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblNomeTitular" Text='<%# Eval("NmPessoa")%>' runat="server" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblTipoPessoa" Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoPessoa")%>' runat="server" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblEmail" Text='<%# Eval("DsEmail")%>' runat="server" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblDtExpiraCadastro" Text='<%# Eval("DtExpiraCadastro")%>' runat="server" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Faço a seguinte pergunta. Caso eu tenha um método que me retorna uma lista e pegar cada item da lista e popular meu repeater, tipo, <%#Eval("Campo_1")%> eu posso garantir que tenho aí um DataSource, sem a necessidade de explicitar?

É nesse método que eu preencho o meu repeater.

```
private void PreencherTitluarAvalista(List<ENTSPTitularesAvalistas> palstPessoas)
        {
            //Declarações
            List<ENTSPTitularesAvalistas> vlstTitular = null;
            List<ENTSPTitularesAvalistas> vlstAvalista = null;

            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializações
                vlstTitular = new List<ENTSPTitularesAvalistas>();
                vlstAvalista = new List<ENTSPTitularesAvalistas>();

                //Desenvolvimento
                if (palstPessoas != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < palstPessoas.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (palstPessoas[i].CdFuncaoPessoa == 1)
                        {
                            vlstTitular.Add(palstPessoas[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vlstAvalista.Add(palstPessoas[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (vlstTitular.Count > 0)
                {
                    rptTitulares.DataSource = vlstTitular;
                    rptTitulares.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    rptTitulares.DataSource = null;
                    rptTitulares.DataBind();
                }

                if (vlstAvalista.Count > 0)
                {
                    rptAvalistas.DataSource = vlstAvalista;
                    rptAvalistas.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    rptAvalistas.DataSource = null;
                    rptAvalistas.DataBind();
                }

                switch (int.Parse(cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue))
                {
                    case 1:

                        pnlTitulares.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoTitutlar.Visible = false;


                        pnlAvalistas.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoAvalista.Visible = false;

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        pnlTitulares.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoTitutlar.Visible = false;

                        pnlAvalistas.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoAvalista.Visible = false;

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        pnlTitulares.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoTitutlar.Visible = false;

                        pnlAvalistas.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoAvalista.Visible = false;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        pnlTitulares.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoTitutlar.Visible = false;

                        pnlAvalistas.Visible = true;
                        pnlNovoAvalista.Visible = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você setou o [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) e deu [DataBind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s1th73f0(v=vs.110).aspx) nele? Verifique e comente.

Comment: Achoe que é exatamente isso. O pessoal do SO me disse isso.

Comment: Onde você está passando os dados (lista de itens) a esse seu segundo repeater "rptTitulares"?

Comment: Então, isso é que eu estou falando. Não consigo ver explicitamente. O que tenho são métodos retornando valores e sendo pegos no asp.net com a função Eval()

Comment: @Fernando, achei sim, foi mal. Realmente existe sim explicitamente o DataBind() em cima do repeater. Acho que agora consegui encontrar o caminho.

Comment: achei estranho mesmo, pois sem Dados, não há logica para o `Repeater` funcionar, afinal o conceito de `DataSource` é de fonte de dados, seja ele uma lista, uma `query` (Cursor), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como citado nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46905/meu-repeater-n%C3%A3o-renderiza-no-browser?noredirect=1#comment94472_46905) aparentemente o que lhe falta é setar o [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) e aplicar um [DataBind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s1th73f0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Você tem que definir uma fonte de dados ([DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)) para o [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater(v=vs.110).aspx), então para cada item da lista setada no DataSource ele vai fazer uma interação (seu funcionamento é como um for, onde em cada interação ele renderizar um template).

E também é necessario que você de um [DataDind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s1th73f0(v=vs.110).aspx), para informar ao Repeater que os dados do DataSource foram atualizados.

Em C# você pode fazer algo similar a isso **(Recomendo)**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         rptHistoricoAnalises.DataSource = fonteDados.BuscarHistoricoAnalises();
         rptHistoricoAnalises.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Ou em ASP.net, via [DataSourceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasourceid(v=vs.110).aspx), [aqui exemplo completo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasourceid(v=vs.110).aspx) **(Não aconselho, você perde o controle sobre as conexão, sem contar que se você trabalha, com camadas como: Dao/Repository, Domain, por exemplo, você estará ignorando todos, perdendo todas as vantagens de sua utilização)**:

```
<asp:repeater id="Repeater1"       
        datasourceid="SqlDataSource1"
        runat="server">

        <headertemplate>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td><b>Product ID</b></td>
              <td><b>Product Name</b></td>
            </tr>
        </headertemplate>

        <itemtemplate>
          <tr>
            <td> <%# Eval("ProductID") %> </td>
            <td> <%# Eval("ProductName") %> </td>
          </tr>
        </itemtemplate>

        <footertemplate>
          </table>
        </footertemplate>
      </asp:repeater>

            <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"          
            connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnection%>" 
        selectcommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM [Products] Where ProductID <= 10"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>
```